# Manage uiview and uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I created an uiview , that contained , many textfields , and I have an uiviewcontroller with xib file responsible for making signature  .Is it possible to add this viewcontroller to my uiview in order to have this componant of drawing signature in the footer of my uiview ??

Comment: don't quite understand your setup. can you show your view and viewcontroller classes?

Comment: thank you for reply. My view contains some textfields , and the viewcontroller with xib file  allows me to draw signature .is it possible to use the viewcontroller as a subview and show the component of drawing in the footer

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)init { //parent view
    ...
    FooterViewController *fvc = [[FooterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNibName" bundle:nil];
    [self addSubview: fvc.view];
    fvc.view.origin = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height - fvc.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

this is how you can create your viewController from xib file and add its view to the main view. assuming this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would hope the main view has its own viewController, which is where I would add this code, as I would probably want to store FooterViewController's instance as a variable somewhere (preferably in MainViewController, and not MainView)

Comment: If it is ViewController's loadView method, then it should add the fvc.view to its view subviews (UIViewController doesn't have addSubview: method). Also, it has to add fvc to its childViewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, the easiest way to go is to drag a Container View object from the Object library (where buttons, labels, etc. are) to your view controller's view. This will create a child view controller that you can handle separately and that will be already resized to mirror the size of the container view controller.